# Prove or Disprove Θ

Tags: asymptotics

I want to prove or disprove that $3n^3 +n^2\log(n) = Θ(n^3)$. I'm aware that I will need to either prove or disprove both big-o and big-Ω to prove or disprove Θ. I am simply struggling to do so. Help appreciated.

Comment: you should consider up voting and accepting answers, or ask for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$n^3<3n^3 +n^2\log(n)<4n^3$$

Asymptotically, since $\log(n)<n$, the left inequality shows $\Omega(n^3)$ and the right shows $O(n^3)$

Comment: The notation $f(n)$ does not seem used very much :)

Comment: @ClementC. Lol. Yeah, I decided not to.

Comment: "for large $n$" Actually, for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: Hey, people have differing views of the meaning of "large"...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** letting $a_n = \frac{3n^3 + n^2\log n}{n^3}$, you have 
$$a_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 3$$
so, as a convergent sequence, the (positive) sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. (Even more, for some $n_0$ big enough, you can also say that $2.9 \leq a_n \leq 3.1$ for all $n\geq n_0$.)